# How to matrix reshape in R

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I got two large matrix with this format:

```
row.names  1    2     3   ...          row.names  1    2   3  ....   

A          0.1 0.2 0.3                   A        1    1   1 
B          0.4 0.9 0.3                   B        2    3   1
C          0.9 0.9 0.4                   C        1    3   1
.
```

And I want to obtain something like this:

```
X  S   CONF P
1  A   0.1  1
1  B   0.4  2
1  C   0.9  1
2  A   0.2  1
2  B  ......
```

Getting the colnames in one column and repeat the rownames and the information per each of the column names.

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you have tables or dataframes? Please provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have large matrix, and I want the colnames to rows and the rownames repeated each time the column name changes .

Comment: Well a reproducable example would help, but they do actually say "two large matrix"...

Comment: I know not a good title, I changed it for matrix sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with some `rep` and `c` work:

```
out <- data.frame(X = rep(colnames(conf), each = nrow(conf)),
                  S = rep(rownames(conf), ncol(conf)),
                  CONF = c(conf), P = c(P))
out
#   X S CONF P
# 1 1 A  0.1 1
# 2 1 B  0.2 1
# 3 1 C  0.3 1
# 4 2 A  0.4 2
# 5 2 B  0.9 3
# 6 2 C  0.3 1
# 7 3 A  0.9 1
# 8 3 B  0.9 3
# 9 3 C  0.4 1
```

@Thomas had a similar approach (but one which matches the answer you show in your question). His answer looked like this:

```
cbind.data.frame(X = rep(colnames(conf), each=nrow(conf)),
                   S = rep(rownames(conf), times=nrow(conf)), 
                   CONF = matrix(t(conf), ncol=1),
                   P = matrix(t(P), ncol=1))
```

Comment: I'll delete my answer, since apparently we had the same idea. But I think it's better to `t` the matrices, so it produces the order OP requested.

Comment: @Thomas, I thought so too, but this answer matches their "accepted" answer. If you don't mind, I'll edit in your answer here too as an alternative. Or you could just keep your answer. It'll get a vote from me at least for thinking along the same lines :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking about matrices, I would convert to a data frame, add the rownames as a column and then "melt" each data.frame...

```
conf <- matrix(
  c(0.1, 0.4, 0.9,
    0.2, 0.9, 0.9,
    0.3, 0.3, 0.4),
  ncol=3, byrow=T
)
rownames(conf) <- c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(conf) <- 1:3

P <- matrix(
  c(1, 2, 1,
    1, 3, 3,
    1, 1, 1),
  ncol=3, byrow=T
)
rownames(P) <- c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(P) <- 1:3

library(reshape)
conf <- cbind(as.data.frame(conf), "S"=rownames(conf))
P <- cbind(as.data.frame(P), "S"=rownames(P))
out <- merge(melt(conf, id="S"), melt(P, id="S"), by=c("variable", "S"))
colnames(out) <- c("X", "S", "CONF", "P")
```

Comment: At least with "reshape2" (not sure about "reshape"), this is much simpler: `merge(melt(conf), melt(P), by = c("Var2", "Var1"))`.